# Dropdown menu for alphabets

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am creating a dropdown list on HTML.
I know you can create via the option method:

```
<select name ="letter" id="letter">
 <option value="a">A</option>
 <option value="b">B</option>
 <option value="c">C</option>
 <option value="d">D</option>
(... to Z)
</select>
```

I was wondering if there was any other methods to construct a dropdown menu for letters ? I have seen it done with jquery was wondering if there was any method with javascript?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a library for JavaScript, so everything that you can do with jQuery, you can also do with vanilla JavaScript.

You could do that like this:

```js
const selectHtmlElement = document.querySelector("#letter");

const alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for(let letter of alphabet ){
  let optionHtmlElement = document.createElement("option");
  optionHtmlElement.value = letter.toLowerCase();
  optionHtmlElement.textContent = letter;
  selectHtmlElement.appendChild(optionHtmlElement);
}
```